# I am trying to stream video in python over socket communication, but it fails?

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, pickle

I am trying to stream video in python over socket communication, but it fails? What am I doing wrong? My goal is to be able to capture an image with my webcam, sterilize it and then send it through socket. The problem is that at the receiving end I get this:

[this is supposed to show the received image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeRmH.png)
Here is the code:

server:

```
import socket,cv2,pickle                                     
serversocket = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
host = socket.gethostname()                           
port = 9999                                           
serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  
serversocket.listen(5)                                           
while True:
   clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()      
   print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
   if clientsocket:
      vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
      while(vid.isOpened()):
         img, frame = vid.read()

         gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
         print(frame)
         a = pickle.dumps(frame)
         clientsocket.send(a)

         b = pickle.loads(a)
   clientsocket.close()
```

client:

```
import socket,cv2,pickle


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 


host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999


s.connect((host, port))                               

data = []
while True:

    packet = s.recv(4096)
    if not packet: break
    data.append(packet)
    k=0
    try:
        data_arr = pickle.loads(b"".join(data))
        print(data_arr)
        if k<1:
            cv2.imshow('frame',data_arr)
        k = k + 1
        data=[]
    except:
        continue
s.close()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should not be unpickling the data until your `while True` loop exits. Only then has the entire frame been received.

Comment: But if I do that I will only be  unpickling only one frame where as I want a live stream (multiple frames per second).

Comment: Then you need to define a protocol for determining where the boundaries of the pickled elements are. A simple protocol involves prefixing every item by a 64-bit integer containing its length, encoded as 8 bytes in big-endian order.

Comment: I would recommend using something meant for streaming, like [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide). All the OpenCV streaming examples I see online send individual frames, and just compress the individual frames. [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) should work for Python.

Answer (score 0):

The struct is our friend here! It is part of the python standard library string services.
It interprets strings as packed binary data and performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings. This is helpful handling binary data in files, socket network connections and other sources. In server.py, the frame matrix is pickled dump as a string in variable a and then used struct.pack to add a reference payloadsize (for the string in a). The payload_size is attached using + to the a and then .sendall sends the whole frame. To simply explain it, lets suppose our frame is just 3x3 matrix:

frame=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

a = pickle.dumps(frame)

The pickled form of frame is shown below as a string:

b'\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\
x01K\x00\x85q\x02C\x01bq\x03\x87q\x04Rq\x05(K\x01K\x03K\x03\x86q\x06cnumpy
\ndtype\nq\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00i4q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03X\x01\x00
\x00\x00

Here payload_size: len(a) is 193 and its string representation in a 4 byte 'L' format is b'\xc1\x00\x00\x00'. 
Then, message = struct.pack("L", len(a))+a

b'\xc1\x00\x00\x00\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\
x01K\x00\x85q\x02C\x01bq\x03\x87q\x04Rq\x05(K\x01K\x03K\x03\x86q\x06cnumpy
\ndtype\nq\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00i4q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03X\x01\x00
\x00\x00

And now the message also contains the payload_size infront of the data. The len(message) = 197.
In client.py the s.recv(4096) means at the most 4096 bytes will be received through a blocking call.
The data is appended to the string in 4096 bytes per packet. The rest of the part is quite obvious.
I hope this little explanation would be helpful! The working server.py and client.py are below for your reference:

server.py

```
    import socket,cv2,pickle
    import struct
    serversocket = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 9999
    serversocket.bind((host, port))
    serversocket.listen(5)

    while True:
        clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()

        print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
        if clientsocket:
            vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            while(vid.isOpened()):
                img, frame = vid.read()
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                print(frame)
                a = pickle.dumps(frame)
                message =struct.pack("L", len(a))+a
                clientsocket.sendall(message)
                cv2.imshow('Transmitted',frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                if key == ord("q"):
                    clientsocket.close()
```

client.py

```
    import socket,cv2,pickle
    import struct
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 9999
    s.connect((host, port))
    data = b""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize("L") 
    while True:
        while len(data) < payload_size:
            packet= s.recv(4096)
            if not packet: break
            data += packet
        packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
        data = data[payload_size:]
        msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0]
        while len(data) < msg_size:
            data += s.recv(4096)
        frame_data = data[:msg_size]
        data = data[msg_size:]
        frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
        cv2.imshow('Received',frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord("q"):
            break
    s.close()
```